# Efficient life hack to peel a jicama

Tags: food, efficiency

The [jicama (yam bean)](http://www.nutrition-and-you.com/jicama.html) is a delicious snack.  But peeling one is not the most pleasant experience.  It can be quite time consuming.  The fact that the peel contains a fat-soluble organic toxin (rotenone) requires that the peel be completely removed.

Can anyone recommend a quick, efficient, and safe method to peel a jicama?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a "housewife's" peeler...

[image]

use a rapid peeler...

[image] [image]

Once the utensil of only professional kitchens, now available to everyone & really really cheap for a basic one. One pound/euro/dollar. You'll never use a 'sideways' peeler again.

*Note* - you can peel any reasonably smooth & regular spherical/oval vegetable in 21 'strokes', approx 14 covers the main body, the rest to pick up the 'ends'. So, if you need fewer strokes/higher speed  with high volume output, choose larger vegetables.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a vegetable peeler as shown:

[image: wikiHow Screenshot]

If boiling does not matter, you can follow these steps:

1. Take a kitchen vessel of water just to immerse your required number of jicama
2. Put jicama into this vessel
3. Boil the vessel on the flame until you see the skin of jicamas peeling off.
4. Take the vessel out of flame and let it cool down.
5. After cooling you can peel off the skin using your bare hand.